Automatically open folders with profile selection
I’ve set up multiple Profiles in VS Code, and each profile has its own set of folders that I regularly use. When I open a new window with a specific profile, I’d like those folders to be automatically attached to the new window.
Currently, I go to: File → New Window With Profile → Select Profile
But after selecting the profile, I still have to manually attach the folders I need. Ideally, when I select a profile, the new window should automatically include the folders I've set up for that profile, rather than needing to attach them from this prompt:

